# Choose position of cursor after a live template

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

In IntelliJ IDEA, I have defined a live template like this:

```java
@Inject
private void postInject() {
  //I want the cursor to be placed here after the execution of the live template.
}
```

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to place the cursor inside of the method body after expanding the live template?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Sure. Just put the special `$END$` variable to that position.

Help documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html#pdtv

Comment: Where can I find the documentation for this?

Comment: Note that if there are variables that are not flagged as "Skip if defined", then the cursor will tab through them first before arriving at $END$.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html

Here is documentation about this feature.

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple stops and jump to next by TAB button?

Comment: Just wanted to say how much better you have made my life just now. Thank you sir.

@Matiss as Nathan said, you can put $var$ or whatever you wanna call your variables before $END$ and it will tab through each of them.